# How to get url path info into a form variable

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, uri

I am creating a module for Drupal 7 that has form that will appear in a block. What I would like to do is get the url for the page that the block appears on (when displayed to the user) and store it in a hidden variable so that it can be processed later. Is this possible and how would you go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to store the data depends on what you want to achieve with that data or how you want to process it afterwards. The easiest solution for that is probably using [watchdog()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/watchdog/7) after form submission:

```
watchdog('myblock', $url);
```

To get the current path there is [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7):

```
$url=current_path();
```

Please beware that you must disable caching for that block to have the code in your block processed all the time. [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically) is an answer on how to create a block programmatically in Drupal.

Comment: If I understand you correctly a do the following with my form value variable: '#value'=>current_path(); and this will get the current path when the block is displayed?

Comment: yes it should. But I am not sure if there might be caching issues. Give it a try though.